# select query for search words in mysql table column words

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table and columns like below

```
  Col1   Col2    Col3       ID  
  test   drive   italy      1  
  meat   foreign italian    2  
  meats  fresh   car italy  3  
  italy  meats   vegetarian 4  
  italy  wine    rain       5
```

I need a select query for above table on words search..for example

if i search like 'italy meats', i should be get output:

```
2,3,4 ID's
```

if i search like 'vegetarian italy meats' it should be get output

```
4 only
```

Comment: yes...i am php developer..for my project i need this mysql query

Comment: Its just creating a mysql to get the expected results...sorry, firstone...i am not that much in explainations

Comment: why you have two columns "col2" ? does your table contain html or is it just a problem with formatting? i think you should edit your question and make it clearear, and also please show us if you already tried something

Comment: Its 'col3'...by mistake i typed...as col2 ...my apologies for this confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> select * from table name where 
>   (match(col1,col2,col3) against(italy)
>   and
>   match(col1,col2,col3) against(meats)
>   or
>   match(col1,col2,col3) against(italian)
>   and
>   match(col1,col2,col3) against(meats)
>   or
>   match(col1,col2,col3) against(italy)
>   and
>   match(col1,col2,col3) against(meat)
>   or
>   match(col1,col2,col3) against(italian)
>   and
>   match(col1,col2,col3) against(meat)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATCH AGAINST: [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE MATCH(col1, col2, col3) 
AGAINST('+italy +meats' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Hi, Luca Giardina..i used above query..its showing only 'italy' column results also...in results italy and meats should be appear

Comment: I added the "+" char on keywords.

Comment: Now also its getting same results

Comment: added IN BOOLEAN MODE.. sorry i can't test it :)

Comment: Ok i understood, it's a very complex query..
If you wanna do it on your own: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

add all the case you need and nest the selects.

Comment: Iam also trying above URL things..but i am not getting...exact out put as i expect